# Idle PyCharm consumes >100% CPU on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, pycharm, cpu-usage, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm is just opened. Nothing is compiling, updating etc. Nevertheless, CPU consumption (of Java) is more than 100%.

What does it do, how to know it?

Answer (score 3):

You can [capture a thread dump using jstack](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-doesn-t-respond) or [capture a CPU snapshot using YourKit](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems).